# How to UPDATE values to decimal in MySql?

Tags: mysql

There are semi-integer strings in my table:

```
1
0
wrong
2
-1
4/5
none
+1
+1 when not -1
```

I can successfully convert with selecting: `SELECT CAST(col AS DECIMAL)`

```
1
0
0
2
-1
4
0
1
1
```

which kind of good result, I want to set decimal where its possible or 0. So Im using:

```
UPDATE table SET col = CAST(col AS DECIMAL)
```

*it says: 1292 Truncated incorrect DECIMAL value +1*

why cant it just get over?

Comment: MySQL does this check when you're storing data into the column, not when you're just selecting, to avoid inadvertently losing data due to the conversion.

Comment: but the column is VARCHAR so it accepts anything

Comment: It checks whether the `CAST` truncates whenever it's being used as the source of an assignment to a column.

Comment: If you do `SHOW WARNINGS` after the `SELECT` you'll see the warning. When it's in an `UPDATE` it upgrades it to an error.

Comment: Investigate whether the value is valid for conversion using the appropriate REGEXP expression, and use CASE according to the test result.